# How do Magento developers create Magento code?

Tags: magento2, magento-1

This may be a stupid question but I wanted to ask this out of curiosity.

**How did Magento's developers create the whole Magento framework?**

If you check Magento 2's `vendor/magento` folder, you will find more than `35000` files in it. I am just curious. Do Magento's developer team create all these files manually? Do they write every line of code by their hands? Or do they have an automated tool like module creator to create modules to further modify as per requirements?

> Feel free to move this question to its respective site if you feel it
> does not belong here.

Comment: I personally write all the code myself as generators can have mistakes also deprecated code as for the core id say a lot of it has been rewritten from the ground up as M1 and M2 are technically different programming languages